# Why do these float calculations return different values?

Tags: objective-c, c, math, floating-point

I'm working with an iOS project where I have to do a bit of math. Can anyone explain to me why these two implementations return different results?

```
float total = 31/30;
NSLog(@"%f", total); // returns 1.00000 in console

float total2 = 31/30.0;
NSLog(@"%f", total2); // returns 1.03333 in console
```

Comment: [Integer division.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3602827/139010)

Comment: The first operation isn't a "float calculation".

Comment: When computing floating point on a computer, some finite decimal results correspond to infinite binary sequences.  For example .3 base 10 is .010101010101.... base 2.

Answer (score 0):

In the majority of computer languages, division involving two integers will have an integer result, the floor of the real result.

In C division, the type of the result is the type of the most precise number in the calculation. In your first example, both `31` and `30` are integers, and so the result is then the integer `1` which is cast to a float to result in `1.00`. In your second example, while `31` is an integer, `30.0` is a literal float, and the calculation has a float result, which is than stored in your variable (`1.033333...`).

Comment: There are a few languages where there's a separate operator for integer division vs float division.  I'm thinking Pascal (or at least some versions of it) uses `%` for integer division.

Comment: @HotLicks: Interesting. There are also some languages, like Common Lisp that avoid this entirely and use rational numbers unless you force them to compute the division.

Comment: The sentence “the type of the result is the type of the most precise number in the calculation” does not reflect the actual clause of the C standard, where it is much clearer that promotions happen on the *operands*. This matters because there is not always a “most precise” type between two types, for instance when adding a 32-bit `int` and a 32-bit `float`. Lastly, in “the majority of computer languages”, the integer division is not the floor but the truncation (towards zero) of the real result.

Comment: @Hot Licks: It's been a long time now, but I seem to remember that the integer division in Pascal used to be **div**, not **%**?

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy - You may be right, it's been a long time for  me too... probably 1985 or so.  But I'm pretty sure there was at least one language that used `%`, possibly PL/S.